# Apply lemmas to bound variables

Tags: isabelle

I can prove the following lemma:

```
lemma lem1: assumes "(a::real) ≤ b / c" and "c > 0" shows "a * c ≤ b"
using assms
using pos_le_divide_eq[of "c" "a" "b"] by auto
```

however, if I use bound variables, the proof does not work.

```
lemma lem2: assumes "∀a b c. (a::real) ≤ b / c" and "∀c. c > 0" shows "∀a b c. a * c ≤ b"
using assms
using pos_le_divide_eq[of "c" "a" "b"]
```

Inserting the ∀ quantifier into the pos_le_divide_eq changes the data type so that is not possible. How can I solve lem2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current reading of `lem2` the first and the last assumption talk about different `c`, i.e. `∀c. c > 0` could also be written as `∀d. d > 0`, whereas in `lem1` both `c` refer to the same variable.

So, if `c` in the first formula should always be positive, there should be just one assumption `∀a b c. (a::real) ≤ b / c ∧ c > 0`. Alternatively, if any value is expected to be positive, the second assumption needs to clarify what is the type of `c` similar to the way it is specified in the first assumption: `∀c. (c :: real) > 0`.

After applying either change `lem2` can be proved by `auto` without `using pos_le_divide_eq[of "c" "a" "b"]`.